# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory trying to open a file in python

Tags: python, csv

I  am new to Python so please forgive the following basic code and problem, but I have been trying to figure out what is causing the error I am getting.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. loop through a specific folder
2. iterate each csv files in that specific folder
3. perform calculations

Here is my code:

```
    import os
    import csv

    def get_all_files(directory):
        dir_list = os.listdir(directory)
        csv_files = []
        for e in dir_list:
            if e.endswith('.csv'):
               csv_files.append(e)
         return csv_files

    def sum_from_csv(csv_file):
        cr = csv.reader(open(csv_file, 'r'))
        cr.next()
        file_content=cr.readlines()

        #initialize throughput total as zero
        throughput_total=0
        #array to save throughput in every iteration
        throughput_dataset=[]

        for line in file_content:
          line=line.strip()
          data=line.split(",")[1]
          float_data=float(data)
          throughput_total+=float_data
          throughput_dataset.append(float_data)
        #to calculate number of dataset
        dataset_length=len(throughput_dataset)
        throughput_average=throughput_total/dataset_length
        throughput.append(throughput_average)
        print "Throughput-total is",throughput_total
        print "Average is",throughput_average

   csv_files = get_all_files('/home/gwthamy/Desktop/MyProject/siddhi-benchmarks/filter-4.0.0-M20/filtered-results-filter-4.0.0-M20')

   for each in csv_files:
        sum_from_csv(each)
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output-0-1502441456439.csv'
```

I have confirmed that the folder and file do exist. What is causing the IOError and how to I resolve it? Also, is there anything else wrong with my code that would prevent me from performing the entire task?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a good practice to use `raw` strings to represent paths in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work !

```
import os

dir = '/home/gwthamy/Desktop/MyProject/siddhi-benchmarks/filter-4.0.0-M20/filtered-results-filter-4.0.0-M20'
for each in get_all_files(dir):
    sum_from_csv(os.path.join(dir, each))
```